# How to mock jdbcTemplate.query with parameters (Object[]{})

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, jdbctemplate

I'm trying using mockito to mock jdbcTemplate and call the method query passing it parameters using Object[]{}.

I'm making the unit test for my DAO layer I want to mock jdbcTemplate and call the method query and pass the sql string,a RowMapper and parameters using Object[] {}

```
public List<EntityType> myDaoMethod(Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin)
            throws NotDataFoundException {
        log.info("entering => myDaoMethod");
        log.info("param => fechaInicio :" +  fechaInicio);
        log.info("param => fechaFin :" +  fechaFin);

        log.debug("Se ejecutando consulta...");
        try {

            List<EntityType> query = jdbcTemplate.query(QueryStrs.MY_QUERY,
                    new Object[] {fechaInicio, fechaFin},
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<EntityType>(EntityType.class));
            log.debug("Se ejecuto consulta. ");

            return query;
        }catch(DataAccessException e) {
            log.error("No se encontro informacion en la consulta myDaoMethod (2)", e);
            throw new NotDataFoundException(e);
        }finally {
            log.info("exiting => myDaoMethod");
        }
    }
```

```
    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Test
    public void myTestMethod() throws NotDataFoundException {

        List<EntityType> listValue = new ArrayList<>();

        listValue.add(new EntityType((short) 2, "modem 2"));
        listValue.add(new EntityType((short) 1, "modem"));

        when(jdbcTemplate.query(any(String.class),any(Object[].class), any(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(listValue);

        MyDao dao = new MyDaoImpl(jdbcTemplate);
        List<EntityType> otrasAdicionalesPorRangoFecha = dao.myDaoMethod(any(Date.class), any(Date.class));

        Assert.assertNotNull(otrasAdicionalesPorRangoFecha);
        Assert.assertTrue(!otrasAdicionalesPorRangoFecha.isEmpty());
//      Assert.assertArrayEquals(listValue.toArray(), otrasAdicionalesPorRangoFecha.toArray());

    }
```

The trace result is

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
-> at com.oracle.reporter.tddtest.rrhhcomision.OtrasAdicionalesDaoTest.testBuscarOtrasAdicionalesPorFecha(OtrasAdicionalesDaoTest.java:80)
-> at com.oracle.reporter.tddtest.rrhhcomision.OtrasAdicionalesDaoTest.testBuscarOtrasAdicionalesPorFecha(OtrasAdicionalesDaoTest.java:80)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `dao` is not a mocked object, so you are not supposed
to pass matchers at this point.

Wrong:

```
dao.myDaoMethod(any(Date.class), any(Date.class));
```

Correct:

```
dao.myDaoMethod(new Date(1), new Date(2));
```

Comment: Thank you @second this is the solution.